# trying to erase external SSD that is only seen in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, ssd

I have a SSD drive that was removed from a MacAir and placed into an eclosure. I must have screwed up the directory by deleting files from the drive and not dismounting it because the drive is invisible in DiskUtil. I can see it in Terminal but when I try to erase the drive using diskutil, it starts and gets to 30% then stops with the error message below. The drive has been backed up so I really just want to start all over. The drive was JHFS+ format. **HERE IS WHAT I'VE TRIED**
diskutil cs delete LVG(ID from cs list)Started CoreStorage operation
Unmounting Logical Volumes
Ejecting Logical Volumes
Destroying Logical Volume Group
Error: -69783: Unable to delete the CoreStorage Logical Volume Group
THE CORESTORAGE LIST IS:

CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
I
+--     Logical Volume Group 82251C74-8AB8-4D15-8B47-F4C0B92577A4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------·-

Name:
Status:
Size:
Free Space:
I

MASMac HD
Online
120473067520 8 (120.5 G8)
18948096 8 (18.9 M8)

•

+-<
I

Physical Volume 011056FE-9076-4299-8245-D661C4A2CA2C
-----------------· -----------------------------------

I   Index:
I   Disk:
I   Status:
I   Size:
I

0
diskls2
Online
120473067520 8 (120.5 G8)

+->

### Logical Volume Family 7DBD9F78-448E-430F-82F0-CD0738D38AC1

Encryption Type:
I

None

### +-> Logical Volume 5313F6EA-59A9-4331-BC04-2C385422C682

Disk:   disk2
Status: Online
Size (Total):   120101797888 B (120.1 GB)
Revertible: Yes (no decryption required)
LV Name:    MASMac HD
Volume Name:    MASMac HD
Content Hint:   Apple_HFS

Comment: Can you post the output of `diskutil list` and also post the command you used to attempt the erase.

Comment: Started CoreStorage operation Unmounting Logical Volumes Ejecting Logical Volumes Destroying Logical Volume Group Error: -69783: Unable to delete the CoreStorage Logical Volume Group